# How do I bind unescaped values on an Ember.Select

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

See example here: http://jsbin.com/OfigaJo/1/edit

The gist of the issue is that I can use the triple handlebars to do this by hand, but I can't find any documentation on how to do the same with an Ember.Select view.

I need the indentation to work in order to show hierarchy within the list. An optgroup wouldn't work in this case because the headers aren't selectable, and I need them to be. Also, I could just use a hyphen, but visually that gets painful pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way you can do something like this would be to wrap the strings in your array in `Handlebars.SafeString` **before** you return it as the model for the select view:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var colors = ['colors', '&nbsp;red', '&nbsp;yellow', '&nbsp;blue', 'shapes', '&nbsp;square', '&nbsp;circle'];
    var safeStrings = colors.map(function(color) {
      return new Handlebars.SafeString(color);
    });
    return safeStrings;
  }
});
```

See here for a working [demo](http://jsbin.com/EfOpASO/10/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried that, but the &nbsp; has to be there because the indentation communicates hierarchy. Replacing them with actual spaces causes the indentation to break. Sorry :( - should've communicated that in the question. I'll update it!

Comment: @JeremyMassel, I fiddled a little more and got it working... please have a look I've updated my answer and the demo jsbin, hope it helps.